# Group by size category as separate array in laravel php

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have on table size_chart

```
| id | category | size | created_at          | updated_at | deleted_at |
+----+----------+------+---------------------+------------+------------+
|  1 | Regular  | S    | 2017-10-11 09:35:14 | NULL       | NULL       |
|  2 | Regular  | XS   | 2017-10-11 09:39:34 | NULL       | NULL       |
|  3 | Regular  | M    | 2017-10-11 09:39:37 | NULL       | NULL       |
|  4 | Regular  | xxl  | 2017-10-11 13:03:52 | NULL       | NULL       |
|  5 | Regular  | l    | 2017-10-11 13:03:59 | NULL       | NULL       |
|  6 | Regular  | xm   | 2017-10-11 13:04:03 | NULL       | NULL       |
|  7 | Small    | em   | 2017-10-11 13:05:04 | NULL       | NULL       |
|  8 | standard | em   | 2017-10-13 07:16:50 | NULL       | NULL       |
```

In this table i have some sample data. I need to group the size based on category 
For.eg

```
Regular = [s,xs,M,l,xm]
standard = [em]
small = [em]
```

How to achieve this on my php controller function

```
public function sizeFetch(Request $request){
        $cat_id = $request->id;
        $size_id = SizeCategory::where('category_id',$cat_id)->pluck('size_id');
    $size_details = SizeChart::whereIn('id',$size_id)->get();

        return $size_details;
    }
```

Now this function return like this

```
[
{
id: 1,
category: "Regular",
size: "S",
created_at: "2017-10-11 09:35:14",
updated_at: null,
deleted_at: null
},
{
id: 2,
category: "Regular",
size: "XS",
created_at: "2017-10-11 09:39:34",
updated_at: null,
deleted_at: null
},
{
id: 3,
category: "Regular",
size: "M",
created_at: "2017-10-11 09:39:37",
updated_at: null,
deleted_at: null
},
{
id: 7,
category: "Small",
size: "em",
created_at: "2017-10-11 13:05:04",
updated_at: null,
deleted_at: null
}
]
```

Please help me to resolve this

Comment: use `groupby` in your query.

Comment: Select size and group them by category. Though I'm too sure how to do this with eloquent.

Comment: Try this `SizeChart::whereIn('id',$size_id)->groupBy('category')->get();` and let me know if it work :)

Answer (score 2):

It's probably easier if you do the grouping after you get results. The problem with grouping within the query is that it doesn't really do what you'd expect. (`GROUP BY` in SQL probably should have been called `AGGREGATE BY` instead)

```
public function sizeFetch(Request $request){
    $cat_id = $request->id;
    $size_id = SizeCategory::where('category_id',$cat_id)->pluck('size_id');
    $size_details = SizeChart::whereIn('id',$size_id)
        ->get()->groupBy("category") //Group by category
             ->map(function ($group) {
                   return $group->pluck("size"); //Pluck size from each category member
             });

    return $size_details;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`GroupBy` is what can help you.
`SizeCategory::where('category_id',$cat_id)->groupBy('size')->pluck('size_id');`

For more [information](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#raw-expressions)